# Oracle SQL can not convert string date to date day

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

I need to convert the following date but I'm getting error:

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

And the SQL:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('December 25th, 2004', 'MONTH DD, YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YY') FROM dual;
```

I think I'm getting error because of the string day format: **25th**

If I remove the 'th' from the string it's working but I need to convert with it.

Answer (score 3):

To take care of all such endings use replace 4 times:

```
with q as (
        select 'December 25th, 2004' dt from dual
        union
        select 'August 1st, 2004'  dt from dual
        union
        select 'December 2nd, 2004' dt from dual
        union
        select 'December 3rd, 2004' dt from dual
       )
select to_char( to_date(replace(replace(replace(replace(dt, 
                                   'th,', ''), 
                                   'st,', ''), 
                                   'nd,',''),
                                   'rd,',''),
                                    'MONTH DD YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YY') from q
```

Comment: If any of these answers are suitable, please mark as correct.  I could use a few points :)

Comment: Ah yes, quite so. Can you make a meaningless change to the edit so I can un-downvote you?

Comment: I changed the answer to include 'August 1st, 2004' so to help with the confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

If you enclose it in double quotes, you can add an arbitrary literal to your format mask.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('December 25th, 2004', 'MONTH DD"th", YYYY'),
  2                 'DD-MM-YY')
  3*   FROM dual
SQL> /

TO_CHAR(
--------
25-12-04
```

Of course, this only works if the string always contains the literal string `th`.  If you have other strings that have other suffixes (i.e. `December 1st, 2004`), you'll get an error

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('December 1st, 2004', 'MONTH DD"th", YYYY'),
  2                 'DD-MM-YY')
  3*   FROM dual
SQL> /
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('December 1st, 2004', 'MONTH DD"th", YYYY'),
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

If you want to handle both, you probably need to parse the original string to remove the suffix before converting the string to a date and then back to a different string

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  WITH x AS (
  2    SELECT 'December 1st, 2004' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3    SELECT 'December 25th, 2004' FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT TO_CHAR(
  6           TO_DATE( SUBSTR( str, 1, INSTR( str, ',' ) - 3 ) ||
  7                      SUBSTR( str, INSTR( str, ',' ) ),
  8                    'MONTH DD, YYYY' ),
  9           'DD-MM-YY' )
 10*   FROM x
SQL> /

TO_CHAR(
--------
01-12-04
25-12-04
```

Comment: the substr is a pretty clean way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

It would work without `th`, `st` and so on, i.e.:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(
       REGEXP_REPLACE('December 25th, 2004',  
                      '([[:digit:]]{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th)', '\1'), 
                      'MONTH DD, YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YY')
  FROM dual;
```

So this expression removes any one or two digits combination concatenated with `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th` and calculates the date from it.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: Of course, this only works if the only suffix in use is "th".  If there are things like "1st" and "2nd" in the string, you'll get an error.  And you can't simply replace all the possible prefixes because months can contain those suffixes as well (i.e. "August" contains "st").

Comment: Yes I know, my first expression was rather considered to be a sample/idea than a complete solution. ORACLE provides a `DDTH` pattern that doesn't work with `VARCHAR2` to `DATE` conversion, unfortunately. So replacing the suffix seems to be the only solution.